# Is there a way to avoid creating a class to match every query's result set, just to do a handoff to Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, thymeleaf

I'm very inexperienced with Java, and have 0 experience with springboot and thymeleaf, but I'm looking into them as a replacement for a system I'm dev on at work.

I'm connecting to an Oracle database and grabbing some records, and then I want to output those to a table using thymeleaf. The handoff between the result set and thymeleaf is where my issue lies. The method I found is to walk the result set and for each row, get every value from every column in the result set and create a new instance of a class that houses those elements. Then that new instance gets loaded into an array list. Once done the array list is handed off to the thymeleaf Model.

My issue is... that seems like a big pain in the butt, we have thousands of queries, do I really need to make a class for every one of those just to format the result set to be compatible with thymeleaf? Ideally, I'd like to just hand the result set to thymeleaf directly. Is there some other method I haven't found yet?

Anyway, current code is below. I'm sure there are many other issues in the code. Please feel free to judge me openly for poor decisions (even if they could be explained away as "it's just a prototype / sample code").

```
package com.somesite.prototype1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller 
public class RootController {
    

    @GetMapping("/tl")
    String getRoot(Model model) {
        
        //instantiate several variables and classes that will be needed later
        Connection connection = null;
        String query = ""
                + "SELECT 1 as id, 'kyle' as name, '555-4837' as phone, 40 as age FROM DUAL UNION "
                + "SELECT 1 as id, 'alex' as name, '555-3567' as phone, 34 as age FROM DUAL UNION ";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        try {
            
            //connect to the database and set up a query
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:jboss/OracleDSWR");
            connection = ds.getConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String selectSql = query;
            
            //Query database and store result the the result set data type
            rs=statement.executeQuery(selectSql);
            
            //get metadata in the result set (column count)
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            
            //create a string with all the records in the result set
            List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>(columnCount);
            while (rs.next()) {
                people.add(new Person(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("phone"), rs.getInt("age")));         
            }
            model.addAttribute("people", people);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "root";
    }   
}
```

```
package com.somesite.prototype1;

public class Person {
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private int age;
    
    public Person (int id, String name, String phone, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.age = age;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    
    
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find any suggestions online, but did think of making a generic class to temporarily hold the records for this handoff, one with properties named "column1", "column2", etc. And then making a function that just loads the result set, in order, into that generic object. like this:

```
public class GenericRecord {
    
    private String column1;
    private String column2;
    private String column3;
    private String column4;
    <etc>
    
    public GenericRecord (String column1, String column2, String column3, String column4, <etc>) {
        this.column1 = column1;
        this.column2 = column2;
        this.column3 = column3;
        this.column4 = column4;
        <etc>
    }

}
```

and then some function like this

```
    public static void resultSetToModel(Model model, ResultSet rs, String attributeName)
    {
        
        //get metadata in the result set (column count)
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        
        //create a string with all the records in the result set
        List<GenericRecord> record = new ArrayList<GenericRecord>(columnCount);
        while (rs.next()) {
            record.add(new GenericRecord(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5) <etc>));           
        }

        model.addAttribute(attributeName, record);
    }
```

I imagine that would work fine, but it would mean I'd have to use the "column1" names in my thymeleaf template, and I'd rather not lose the visibility of the column contents from within the templates, and it seems messy. Is there some way to dynamically generate a class on the fly, and make it's property names match the column names in the result set? Or is there some other angle on how to do this handoff without requiring so much hassle?

Comment: Suggestion: Use a Java `List<String>` or a Java `Map<String, String>` to represent one table row (so, overall, a list of lists, or a list of maps). If it's a list of lists, then the first entry is a list of table headings. If it's a list of maps, then each map's keys are the table headings.  Step 1: see questions like [Java ResultSet copy to generic object or list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23845971/12567365) and various [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=generic+java+object+for+any+jdbc+resultset+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Step 2: Some Thymeleaf to iterate over whatever generic Java structure (list of lists/list of maps) you end up using. You can ask a more specific question, if you have a specific problem. But there is no need to "_dynamically generate a class on the fly_" here. If you _do_ want to, you can look at DynaBeans - e.g. [DynaBeans vs CodeGenerated JavaBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12260113/12567365)

Comment: Maybe have a look at [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/). It generates Java code from your database tables to have type-safe queries. You get back an instance of a Result class that you could iterate over in your Thymeleaf template. (Note: not free if you are using Oracle as your database)

Comment: @andrewJames the list of lists is a great idea. That would be super compact. There’s still some open questions about doing it that way, namely some of our queries aren’t display-ready and need formatting after retrieval, but I think that will work itself out when I get a chance to give your suggestion a shot on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: "_our queries aren’t display-ready_" - Yes, absolutely - you should expect to need some formatting (e.g. for dates). One danger of a generic approach like this: You find yourself, step-by-step, building a full report writer application!